# Is there a way to generalize clock algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

As in the difference between $9$ o'clock am and $5$ o'clock pm is $8$ hours. I thought working in mod $12$ would work but that only seems to work for addition as in:
$$9+8=17$$
And $17$ mod $12$ is $5$. That works, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get it to work for subtraction. Is there a way to build an algebraic group that behaves a clock?

Comment: Well, you have $5-8=-3$ and $-3 \equiv 9 \pmod {12}.$

Comment: Please give more context, e.g. what specific problem do you have with subtraction? What is your definition of "mod 12" arithmetic? Are you using congruences, or quotient rings, or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ are equivalence classes of integers, like so:

$$[a]_n:=\{b\in\Bbb Z: n\mid a-b\}.$$

Addition is defined like so:

$$[x]_n+_n[y]_n:=[x+y]_n,$$

where $+$ is standard addition. It follows, then, that subtraction is defined like so:

$$[x]_n-_n[y]_n:=[x-y]_n,$$

which is, indeed, $[x]_n+_n[(-y)]_n$.